# How do I make an alert() that gives the result of a if else statement using external JS

Tags: javascript, if-statement, alert

I'm new to HTML and JS and I'm trying to make an alert when a button is pressed on the webpage that says "Good day" or "Good evening"
The problem is that I need to do it on an external JS and I'm having trouble doing it. Here is the code I have so far:

```
  var hour = new Date().getHours(); 
  var greeting;
  if (hour < 18) {
    greeting = "Good day";
  } else {
    greeting = "Good evening";
  }
  alert(greeting)
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I'm doing this for a project, and it says that no script tags should be contained in index.html
Here is my current index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" 
</head>
<body onload="loading()">
<div id="musicartists"></div>
<script src="script.js"></script>

<h1 onclick="greeting()">Greetings!</h1>
<button onclick="birthday()">My birthday</button>
<button onclick="myfunction()">Time based greeting</button>

<h3 id="musicartists">My favorite sports:</h3>
<p class="sports">Skiing</p>
<p class="sports">Swimming</p>


</body>
</html>
```

script.js:

```
// Creates an alert, when a specific button is pressed
function birthday() {
alert('September 9th');
}

// Creates an alert, when the body is loaded
function loading() {
alert("Page loaded successfully!");
}

function myFunction() {
  var hour = new Date().getHours(); 
  var greeting;
  if (hour < 18) {
    greeting = "Good day";
  } else {
    greeting = "Good evening";
  }
  alert(myFunction);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "external js"? A file included in `script`? Post the HTML you're working with, as is there's nothing relating to buttons here.

Comment: and what is external js?

Comment: look at your web inspector for errors. There's an extra `}` in what you posted above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can jam it all into the onclick handler.

```html
<button onclick="alert(new Date().getHours() < 18 ? 'Good Day' : 'Good Eventing')">Time based greeting</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Creates an alert, when a specific button is pressed
function birthday() {
alert('September 9th');
}

// Creates an alert, when the body is loaded
function loading() {
alert("Page loaded successfully!");
}

function myFunction() {
  var hour = new Date().getHours(); 
  var greeting;
  if (hour < 18) {
    greeting = "Good day";
  } else {
    greeting = "Good evening";
  }
  alert(greeting);
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" 
</head>
<body onload="loading()">
<div id="musicartists"></div>

<h1 onclick="greeting()">Greetings!</h1>
<button onclick="birthday()">My birthday</button>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Time based greeting</button>

<h3 id="musicartists">My favorite sports:</h3>
<p class="sports">Skiing</p>
<p class="sports">Swimming</p>

<script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

First off, it's always a good practice to put your `<script>` tag at the bottom of the `<body>` tag, not towards the top.

Next, be sure to note that `myfunction` and `myFunction` are two different variables; `<button onclick="myfunction()">Time based greeting</button>` refers to `myfunction` but the actual function is `myFunction`. Case makes a big difference.

Last, `alert(myFunction);` is actually printing the source code of the function to the screen, rather than the greeting. Instead you would want to do `alert(greeting);`.

That's all I could find for errors, I hope this helped you.